# Split a grand total value into two columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying to split a 'grand total' value into two columns in my query but doing so by maintaining one row in the results.  I am currently using two different `CASE` statements to do so but it ends up creating two rows for each result - each one containing a `NULL`. Is there anyway to do this and only return one one row of results with the grand total split out by the conditions specified?

Example is I have a material that has Quantity 'Blank Qty' of 38 units and an 'Uncovered Qty' of 8 units for a grand total of 46.  I would like to see this in one row - but with the code below I get two rows for this material - one for each type of qty.  I have looked into `PIVOT` but doesn't seem like it would do the trick.

```
CASE
        WHEN MRP.STOCK_TYPE = 'A'
        THEN SUM(MRP.QUANTITY) 
        END AS 'Uncovered Qty', 
    CASE WHEN MRP.STOCK_TYPE <> 'A'
        THEN SUM(MRP.QUANTITY)
        END AS 'Blank Qty'
```

returns:

one row with a value of 'uncovered qty' = NULL and 'blank qty' = 38 
one row with a value of 'uncovered qty = 8 and 'blank qty = `NULL`

Is there some way to get this to return in a single row and avoid the `NULL`

Comment: Based on *Is there some way to get this to return in a single row and avoid the NULL* -> `where your_column IS NOT NULL`

Comment: CASE is not a statement, it is an expression that returns a scalar value. If your starting point is 2 (or more - we don't know) rows that either need to be combined (likely) or filtered then the appropriate logic depends on your goal and the content of these rows. You are already using SUM - which means you are already grouping rows, so the problem most likely lies with your grouping logic which is not posted. You have guesses but guessing is not the most effective way of finding a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bring the condition into the `SUM`s and that will give you both values in one row:

```
SUM (CASE WHEN MRP.STOCK_TYPE  = 'A' THEN MRP.QUANTITY ELSE 0 END) AS 'Uncovered Qty', 
SUM (CASE WHEN MRP.STOCK_TYPE <> 'A' THEN MRP.QUANTITY ELSE 0 END) AS 'Blank Qty'
```

Comment: This is what I'd do - it's easy to extend the technique using a groupby to produce a pivot too. The ELSE 0 can be omitted if you like

Comment: @CaiusJard I like to put it in just to be clear, and also just in case there was a DBMS that didn't like summing NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

add `isnull()` on your subquery to return 0 for nulls and `sum()` the results again.

```
select sum(t1.[Uncovered Qty]) as [Uncovered Qty], sum(t1.[Blank Qty]) as [Blank Qty]
from (select 
        CASE WHEN MRP.STOCK_TYPE = 'A'
        THEN ISNULL(SUM(MRP.QUANTITY), 0) 
        END AS 'Uncovered Qty', 

        CASE WHEN MRP.STOCK_TYPE <> 'A'
        THEN ISNULL(SUM(MRP.QUANTITY), 0)
        END AS 'Blank Qty'
        from table) t1
```